# Node.js does not return value from post request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am sending data to my node.js server using ajax:

```
btn.addEventListener("click",function () {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/buy", {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        body: JSON.stringify({value:input.value}), // data can be `string` or {object}!
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function(res){
        console.log("got it ", res)
        return res.json();
    })
     .then(function(response){
         console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response))
     })
     .catch(function(error ){
         console.error('Error:', error)
     })
})
```

and on my server i do following:

```
app.post('/buy' , ( req , res ) => {
    console.log(req.body.value) // this prints right value
    res.json({"foo":"bar"});
});
```

However my ajax code does not print anything, its like .then in promises is ignored.

Why is this happening? I dont see reason why this shouldnt work.

I am using express.js

Thanks for help!

Comment: Three things to check - did anything get logged on the server? Are you able to see the response on the network tab? Is there any error on the console?

Comment: First, what is your server port.. and what is your front end port? are you using proxy to redirect traffic?

Comment: Open your console, I suspect a CORS issue

Comment: @GuerricP browser console logs nothing, on server , i recieve request from front end

Comment: @AritraChakraborty i dont know what you are talking about so propably not :D

Comment: That doesn't make sense, do you confirm you see `{"foo":"bar"}` in the network tab with a `Content-Type: application/json` header? Also you don't see any `console.log`?

Comment: @GuerricP I dont see anything in network tab, the fetch post request is not there

Comment: Aren't you filtering console messages or network requests?

Comment: @GuerricP my filter is empty in network tab

Comment: what about console?

Comment: @GuerricP browser console is empty, server console prints the right value from request

Comment: I really don't get why you see a log on the server and you don't see anything in network tab... there must be some weird setting on your browser

Comment: res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json') is it being set in server ?

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.addEventListener("click",function () {
console.log('foo')
fetch("http://localhost:3000/buy", {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    body: JSON.stringify({value:input.value}), // data can be `string` or {object}!
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(function(res){
    console.log("got it ", res)
    return res.json();
})
 .then(function(response){
     console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response))
 })
 .catch(function(error ){
     console.error('Error:', error)
 })
})
```

Do you see 'foo' logged on the console?